# Which Arab countries have explicitly stated they support Trump's peace plan for the Israel-Palestine issue?

Tags: united-states, israel, middle-east, palestine, peace-treaty

In a [BBC interview](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-middle-east-51317764/palestinian-pm-defends-stance-on-trump-middle-east-plan) Palestinian PM Shtayyeh said that the presence of Arab countries' ambassadors when Trump announced his peace plan doesn't necessarily mean those countries endorse Trump's plan.

So [entertaining this viewpoint], which Arab countries have expressed unambiguous, explicit support for Trump's plan?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump_peace_plan#International_reactions

Comment: it would be nice if someone sourced a map superimposing the 1967-conquered territories, typically what's referred to by [UN Resolution 242](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_242) with the Trump map.  While 1967 area is relatively homogeneous Trump's is really really fragmented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only no Arab country supports Trump's peace plan, on February 1st the [Arab League stated that it **unambiguously rejects it**](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/feb/01/palestinians-cut-ties-israel-us-trump-peace-plan):

> The Arab League foreign ministers meeting in Cairo said the plan did not meet the minimum aspirations of Palestinians, and the League would not cooperate with the US in implementing it.
>
> The ministers affirmed Palestinian rights to create a state based on land captured and occupied by Israel in the 1967 Middle East war, with East Jerusalem as capital, the final communique said.

It's worth emphasizing that this opposition is shared by the Arab countries which are US allies:

> Foreign ministers from Egypt, Saudi Arabia and Jordan, three close US allies, as well as Iraq, Lebanon and others, said there could be no peace without recognising Palestinian rights to establish a state within the pre-1967 territories.

Comment: As it was getting too long for a comment, I've added a few more details on that meeting that the Times of Israel reported to a separate answer.

Answer (score 12):

None.

Looking through [Wikipedia's article on the plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump_peace_plan#International_reactions) and [Al Jazeera's summary](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/01/world-reaction-trump-middle-east-plan-200128173439574.html), the reactions can be summarized as:

- Bahrain: noncommittal
- Egypt: neutral
- Iraq: no statement
- Jordan: opposed
- Kuwait: opposed
- Lebanon: no statement
- Oman: no statement
- Palestine: opposed
- Qatar: opposed
- Saudi Arabia: opposed
- Syria: no statement
- United Arab Emirates: neutral
- Yemen: Houthi: opposed.  Other factions: no statement.

Additionally, the Arab League has [unanimously rejected the peace plan](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-israel-palestinians-arabs/arab-league-rejects-trumps-middle-east-plan-communique-idUSKBN1ZV3QV?).

Comment: Saudi Arabia, Egypt, Qatar, UAE welcomed Trump’s peace plan. https://www.jpost.com/Middle-East/Saudi-Arabia-Egypt-Qatar-UAE-welcome-Trump-peace-plan-615752 and https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/01/world-reaction-trump-middle-east-plan-200128173439574.html

Comment: @Ben I think they support the effort, not the content of the proposal. E.g. for Qatar, from the [Times of Israel](https://www.timesofisrael.com/qatar-welcomes-us-mideast-peace-plan-but-urges-changes/): *"Qatar responded cautiously on Wednesday to US President Donald Trump’s Israeli-Palestinian peace plan, saying it welcomed efforts to broker “longstanding peace,” but warned that was unattainable without concessions to the Palestinians."* That's diplomatic speak for *Thanks, but no thanks.*

Comment: Look at what they're actually saying, not what the headline is.  Saudi Arabia: "Thank you for your efforts". Qatar: "within the 1967 borders, including East Jerusalem" -- that's an oppose, not a support.  UAE: "This is a starting point for a return to negotiation".

Comment: @Ben, Egypt's statement is more complex, but it boils down to "thank you for your efforts, and Israel and Palestine should resume negotiations under US mediation".

Answer (score 6):

Given the complexity and sensitivity of the situation, unambiguous support for any first-proposal agreement would be highly unlikely.

The following states from the region offered support for the effort to open negotiations.

**Saudi Arabia**

> Saudi Arabia's King Salman reassured the Kingdom's commitment to the
>   Palestinian issue and Palestinian rights, in a phone call with
>   Palestinian President Mahmoud Abbas, the Saudi state news agency
>   reported early on Wednesday.
>
> The foreign ministry said in a statement that it "appreciates the
>   efforts of President Trump's administration to develop a comprehensive
>   peace plan" and also called for the start of "direct peace negotiation
>   between the Palestinian and Israeli sides".

**Egypt**

> Egypt urged Israelis and Palestinians to "carefully study" the
>   proposal. The foreign ministry said in a statement that the plan
>   favours a solution that restores all the "legitimate rights" of the
>   Palestinian people through establishing an “independent and sovereign
>   state on the occupied Palestinian territories".
>
> Egypt, which along with Jordan is the only Arab country to have made
>   peace with Israel, said it appreciates the US administration's efforts
>   to try to resolve the decades-old conflict.

**UAE**

> Yousef al-Otaiba, the United Arab Emirates' ambassador to Washington,
>   said the plan "offers an important starting point for a return to
>   negotiations within a US-led international framework".
>
> "The only way to guarantee a lasting solution is to reach an agreement
>   between all concerned parties," al-Otaiba said in a statement on
>   Tuesday.
>
> "The UAE believes that Palestinians and Israelis can achieve lasting
>   peace and genuine coexistence with the support of the international
>   community."

**Qatar**

> Qatar said it welcomed efforts to broker peace but warned that was
>   unattainable without concessions to the Palestinians.
>
> A statement carried by state-run Qatar News Agency said the country
>   "welcomes all efforts aiming towards a longstanding and just peace in
>   the occupied Palestinian territories". It said Qatar "appreciates the
>   endeavours of President Trump and the current US administration to
>   find solutions for the Palestinian-Israeli conflict", but added that
>   "all solutions should be consistent with international law and the
>   relevant UN resolutions".
>
> "All Arab states, through the Arab League, have adopted in 2002 the
>   Arab Peace Initiative, which articulated a set of principles conducive
>   to a just peace," the statement said.
>
> "The State of Qatar notes in this context that peace cannot be
>   sustainable if Palestinians' rights in their sovereign state within
>   the 1967 borders, including East Jerusalem, and the right of return
>   are not preserved."

Source: https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/01/world-reaction-trump-middle-east-plan-200128173439574.html

Comment: I have trouble seeing Qatar's statement as "support" when they explicitly call for Palestine having the 1967 borders and East Jerusalem, while Trump's plan only grants about 70% of the 1967 area, and denies Palestine all but a sliver of East Jerusalem.

Comment: Saudi Arabia has since come out as a clear "oppose": King Salman has stated that any peace plan must include East Jerusalem as the Palestinian capital, while Trump's plan calls for placing it in Abu Dis.

Answer (score 3):

A few more [details](https://www.timesofisrael.com/after-arab-league-rejects-peace-plan-us-official-laments-approach-as-outdated/) from The Times of Israel... which emphasized some disagreement in the Arab camp, but also some apparent backtracking leading to the consensus statement.

> “It is important … to come out with a constructive stance, a realistic stance and a positive strategy that goes beyond just condemnation,” UAE Minister of State for Foreign Affairs Anwar Gargash said, according to Riyadh-based Arab News.
>
> Nonetheless, the Arab League, a pan-Arab bloc of 22 countries, said in its statement Saturday that it “rejects the US-Israeli ‘deal of the century’ considering that it does not meet the minimum rights and aspirations of Palestinian people.” Arab leaders also vowed “not to… cooperate with the US administration to implement this plan.” [...]
>
> An unnamed Arab diplomat told the Haaretz daily that the US had not fully briefed envoys from Bahrain, the UAE and Oman on the details of the plan before they agreed to attend its unveiling ceremony on Tuesday.
>
> The disappointment with the details of the plan led the three countries to join the other Arab League member states in voting Saturday to reject the plan, he said.